# RestTemplate POST throws 400: Bad Request while calling GraphQL Endpoint

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, graphql, resttemplate

I'm trying to call the [Shopify Partner API](https://shopify.dev/api/partner/getting-started) to validate the authentication. I have tried multiple ways that were successful, for instance, I received a successful response with Postman:

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://partners.shopify.com/2XXXXX8/api/2021-10/graphql.json' \
--header 'X-Shopify-Access-Token: prtapi_...' \
--header 'Cookie: _partners_session=a4a...; monorail_user_token=3648077d-...'
```

I received a successful response when I used `org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient;`:

```java
    try (CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.createDefault()) {
      HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(restUrl);
      httpPost.addHeader("X-Shopify-Access-Token", accessToken);

      try (CloseableHttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost)) {
        int statusCode = httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
        if (statusCode != 200) {
          log.warn("Auth Failed, Response Status:: " + statusCode);
        }
      }
    }
```

and I also received a successful response when I used `okhttp3.OkHttpClient;`

```java
    RequestBody reqbody = RequestBody.create(null, new byte[0]);
    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
    Request request =
        new Request.Builder()
            .url(restUrl)
            .addHeader("X-Shopify-Access-Token", accessToken)
            .post(reqbody)
            .build();

    try {
      Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

But the problem is that I am bound to use only `org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;` I have tried multiple ways to achieve that but for some reason, it's not working:

```java
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.set("X-Shopify-Access-Token", accessToken);
    headers.add("X-Shopify-Access-Token", accessToken); // Just in case

    RequestEntity requestEntity = new RequestEntity(headers, HttpMethod.POST, URI);
    ResponseEntity<String> res = restTemplate.exchange(requestEntity, String.class); // Fails

    MediaType mediaType = MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN;
    RequestEntity requestEntity = RequestEntity.post(uri).headers(headers).contentType(mediaType).build();
    ResponseEntity<String> res = restTemplate.exchange(requestEntity, String.class); // Fails

    headers.setContentType(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN);
    HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<>("", headers);
    String res = restTemplate.postForObject(uri, entity, String.class); // Fails
```

For all the requests above, I'm getting `400 : [Bad Request]`. What am I missing? I am also adding Postman's OKHttp version for reference:

```java
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient().newBuilder()
  .build();
MediaType mediaType = MediaType.parse("text/plain");
RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(mediaType, "");
Request request = new Request.Builder()
  .url("https://partners.shopify.com/2XXXXX8/api/2021-10/graphql.json")
  .method("POST", body)
  .addHeader("X-Shopify-Access-Token", "prtapi_...")
  .addHeader("Cookie", "_partners_session=a4a...; monorail_user_token=3648077d-...")
  .build();
Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
```

Comment: 400: it must be the content type(some forgotten/hidden header)...

Comment: Or... Accept! (String.class sounds *also* not good, here!! ..the API (surely) can offer you "more structured")

Comment: We mostly use `JsonNode.class`. It failed with that as well.

Comment: Do the cookies matter? The curl and postman have it while the RestTemplate call (in the snippet) does not seem to have any. I'm also not sure if setting and adding the access token would produce 2 headers or not (which may or may not be a problem).

Comment: @TimTong No, that's not the case. The cookies don't matter and I have checked the headers with `set`, `add`, and `add & set`. It doesn't work.